# one time rotation Unity

Tags: unity

How do I rotate the object only once after a key press. So after it rotates say 10 degrees upwards, the user can't rotate it anymore.

this is my code which as continuous rotation -:

```
   void Update(){
 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.J))
     transform.Rotate(0, 0, 3f);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `private bool isRotated` variable to the script. This variable stores the information if the user did already rotate this object or not.

Then check that variable in your code.

```
 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.J) && isRotated == false)
     transform.Rotate(0, 0, 3f);
     isRotated = true;
  }
```

Another solution might be to [disable](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html) or even [destroy](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) the component which handles the rotation of the object. But that's of course only an option when the component only handles the rotation and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

@Philipp's answer is correct but I want explain more about limiting

if you want rotate the object only once after a key press you should use Input.GetKeyDown In Update function

but if you want limit rotation between two value min_max you can use [Mathf clamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics))

> function clamp(x, min, max):
>
> if (x < min) then
>   x = min;
>   else if (x > max) then
>   x = max;
>
> return x;
>
> end clamp

Mathf.Clamp(float value, float min, float max);

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RotationController : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update () {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3 (
            transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x,
            transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y,
            Mathf.Clamp (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z, -3, 3)));

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, 3);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            transform.Rotate(0, 0, -3);
    }
}
```

in other way you can use Quaternion to limiting
Quaternion definition:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class degree : MonoBehaviour {
  public float w,x,y,z;
  public float a = 0;


  void Start(){
    a = a / 360 * (float)Mathf.PI * 2;
    w = Mathf.Cos (a / 2);
    x = Mathf.Sin (a / 2);
    y = Mathf.Sin (a / 2);
    z = Mathf.Sin (a / 2);
    print (a);
    gameObject.transform.rotation = new Quaternion (w,x,y,z);
  }
}
```

you should know about
 Degrees 30° 
Radians(exact)π/6
 Radians(approx) 0.524
[learning link](http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/radians.html)

so you can limit rotation:

```
void Update () {
    print (transform.rotation.z);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D) && transform.rotation.z <0.02617695)
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, 3);
}
```